# can we prevent red screen of death in react native using try and catch block

Tags: react-native

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NativeModules
} = React;



var Projectlayout = React.createClass({


  render: function() {

    try{
    return (
      <View >

        <Text>{a.b}
        </Text>
      </View>**strong text**
    )
  }catch(error1){
      console.log("hello errrrr"+error1);

    }
}

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProjectLayout', () => Projectlayout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you want to catch. The example you showed will catch errors in instantiating the `View` class, the `Text` class, and getting the value of `a.b`. If you want to catch errors that occur elsewhere in the lifecycle (`componentWillMount`, `render`, etc.) you will need to place a try-catch in the function you wish to guard.

Comment: my problem is something like whenever i got error in my project, a default render function should called with error message. Your any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should look at where React does that in its code. Specifically the global ErrorUtils object: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/error-guard.js